# How to do a simple transpose/pivot in R

Tags: r, reshape

I simply want to take a dataframe with two columns, one with a grouping variable and the second with values, and transform it so that the grouping variable becomes columns with the appropriate values.  A very simple question, but after searching for about an hour, I cannot find a good answer.  Here is a toy example:

```
var <- c("Var1", "Var1", "Var2", "Var2")
value <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

df <- data.frame(var, value)

df.one <- df[df$var == "Var1", ]
df.two <- df[df$var == "Var2", ]

desired.df <- data.frame(df.one[2], df.two[2])
colnames(desired.df) <- c("Var1", "Var2")

desired.df
```

With more variables and values, this bit of code could become extremely clunky. Can anyone suggest a better method?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `dcast` from the `reshape2` package

Answer (score 6):

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Var1", "Var2"), class = "factor"), 
 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4)), .Names = c("var", "value"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

It looks like it is useful to introduce a new variable that identifies the observation within `var` (I call this `case` below); you can remove it after reshaping it if you like.

With `reshape2`/`plyr`:

```
library("plyr")
library("reshape2")
## add 'case' identifier
df <- ddply(df,"var",mutate,case=1:length(var))
## dcast() to reshape; then drop identifier
dcast(df,case~var)[,-1]
```

With `tidyr` (same strategy):

```
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
df %>% group_by(var) %>%
    mutate(case=seq(n())) %>%
        spread(var,value) %>%
            select(-case)
```

This could probably be done with `reshape()` in base R as well, but I have never been able to figure it out ...

Answer (score 5):

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(split(df$value,df$var))
#  Var1 Var2
#1    1    3
#2    2    4
```

This solution implies that all 'VarN' subsets have equal length.
More general solution will be:

```
z <- split(df$value,df$var)
max.length <- max(sapply(z,length))
data.frame(lapply(z,`length<-`,max.length))
```

which appends NA to shorter lists to make sure that all lists have the same length.

Comment: This of course only works when there are equal numbers of "Var1" and "Var2". More generally (and hideously) this can be done in base as `reshape(cbind(df,count=ave(rep(1,nrow(df)),df$var,FUN=cumsum)),idvar="count",timevar="var",direction="wide")[,-1]`

Comment: @A.Webb, your solution adds some extra output in the case of `df <- structure(list(var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Var1", 
"Var2", "Var3"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 4), case = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("var", "value", "case"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: forcing the length to be greater in order to do NA-padding strikes me as too clever.  I would prefer to write a short NA-padding function (or grab one from a package somewhere: `pad.na(x,n) <- c(x,rep(NA,length.out=max(0,n-length(x)))`

Comment: @BenBolker, that's an officially documented feature: `?length` says "when a vector is lengthened, it is padded out to its new length with NAs (nul for raw vectors)." :)

Comment: I know it's officially documented behaviour. It's just too clever for my taste. It's like using `x+0` to convert from logical to numeric.